# Is there any way to fetch a dropdown selected value with out using model

Tags: model-view-controller, selectlist

Currently i use java script , and pass the value as a query string and catch it in my controller . This causes the page to refresh. Is there any way i can do it without page being refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax if you do not want to reload the whole page. Here i do not mean ajax's begin form. Use ajax call on the javascript part/event where you are fetching the selected value from the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$.ajax` pattern:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { foo: yourData,}, //Here is the data you want to pass into your controller action
            success: function (result) {
                 $('#divName').html(result);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Then you do not need to reload the whole page but only the chosen `div`.